# using JavaScript how to replace some text which is inside a div in html

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am not very good at JavaScript , I have a small question , how can I replace some text which is inside a  for example this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9La6W.png)

I want to replace this My text here with some other text how can I do that using JavaScript

Comment: Post your code as formatted text, not images. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: in the *document*, you *get* the *Element* *By* its *Id* and set the *inner* *HTML* to whatever value you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [`Document.querySelector(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select an element using a [`CSS Selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. Then use the [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property of the element to change it's text value.

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelector("#field_name").innerText = "Changed using JavaScript"
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <div>Not changed using JavaScript</div>
  <div id="field_name">My text here</div>
</div>
```

**Links:**

[`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within
> the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
> selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

[`CSS Selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

> **CSS selectors** define the elements to which a set of CSS rules apply.

[`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

> The `innerText` property of the `HTMLElement` interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that if you get the element (either with getElementById or with querySelector) and than you replace the content with innerHTML.

If you do that it can look like this (very simple example):

```
<div id="test1">
   <div id="field_name">My Text here</div>
</div>

<script>
   document.querySelector("#field_name").innerHTML = "My new Text"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Get element by using `document.getElementById("idname")` or `document.getElementByClass("className")` or `document.querySelector(".class or #id")`

2)Then use `.textContent = "some text"` or `.innetHTML = "some text"`